# Only keep .csv column containing X Y Z data?

Tags: text-processing, sed

How can I keep .csv line data that only contains the words `dog` or `cat` and only check for them on the second column, if the word "dog" appears on any other column but not the 2nd then it should be ignored.

For example if I had:

```
email1.com dog
email2dog.com steve
email3.com cat
```

Expected output:

```
email1.com dog
email3.com cat
```

There maybe a long list of words to keep so if possible load them from another file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -n -e 's/dog$/&/p' -e 's/cat$/&/p' file
email1.com dog
email3.com cat
```

Or you can use `awk`:

```
awk '$2~/^dog|cat$/' file
```

Comment: None of these work, if the other columns have the word "dog" or "cat" in them they also remain.

Comment: @Teddy291: Are you sure? Please give me an example.

Comment: "username random@email.co.uk Keith P Dogville" is still left when it shouldn't be (dog is not on the second column)

Comment: @Teddy291: There's no way it's still left. Did you try my answer?

Comment: "awk '$2~/dog|cat/' newname.csv > new.csv" is the exact command I entered. "username ****isdubay2***@aol.com De***s D***y Decatur Illinois 6***1 UNITED STATES" is still left when it shouldn't be (cat is on the forth column but not second)

Comment: @Teddy291: `$2` contains `cat` in your example, please try the edit.

Comment: cat is not in the second column

Comment: @Teddy291: `cat` was in `DyDecaturIllinois6***1UNITED`. Your file contains tab delimiter instead of spaces. Try the updated to fix it.

Comment: awk '$2~/^dog|cat$/' file still didn't do it. I am not sure how to post {tags} in comments but if you can check http://pastebin.com/6qaBarxE you will see the third column contains "dog" but the second doesn't

Answer (score 1):

A few approaches:

1. If the `dog` or `cat` is always the last word on the line:

   ```
   awk '/(dog|cat)$/' file
   grep -E '(dog|cat)$' file
   sed -n '/\(dog\|cat\)$/p' file
   perl -ne 'print if /(dog|cat)$/' file
   ```
2. If the `dog` or `cat` can be anywhere in the second *space-delimited* field:

   ```
   awk '$2~/dog|cat/' file
   grep -E '^\S+\s+\S*(dog|cat)\S*\s*' file
   perl -ane 'print if $F[1]=~/dog|cat/' file
   sed -nr '/^\S+\s+\S*(dog|cat)\S*\s*/p' file
   sed -n '/^\S\+\s\+\S*\(dog\|cat\)\S*\s*/p' file
   ```
3. To read the search patterns from a file, you can do:

   ```
   awk '{if(NR==FNR){a[$0]++; next}for(p in a){if($2~p){print}}}' patterns  file
   ```

Comment: None of these work, if the other columns have the word "dog" or "cat" in them they also remain.

Comment: @Teddy291 what? You never said you wanted to remove the others! You just asked for commands that print lines whose second field matches `cat` or `dog`. If you want the rest removed, edit your question and tell us so.

Comment: "and only check for them on the second column." I thought I did sorry :( I will edit it.

Comment: @Teddy291 all of the solutions in part 2 and the one in part 3 check the second space-delimited field. The ones in part 1, as stated in the answer, test the _last_ field which works on the example you gave. Are you saying that you want to only print fields 1 and 2 of matching lines and remove all other fields?

Comment: If the word "dog" is in first, third or fourth column but not the second then that line needs to go. Only keep the whole lines of data that contain "dog" or "cat" in the second column.

Comment: @Teddy291 OK, that's precisely what each of the solutions in parts 2 and 3 do. Are you sure your fields are separated by spaces? Not commas or tabs?

Comment: I think they are separated by tabs, when I paste it into notepad they are.

Comment: @Teddy291 you need to be precise, that changes everything. You call your file "csv" which means comma separated values, you give an example with spaces and now you tell us your file has tabs. Please edit your question and make it clear, we don't have access to your data and because of your vagueness both cuonglm and I have wasted our time here.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
{   sed 's/[]$^&\./*[]/\\&/g;s/$/$/'|
    grep -f- ./greppedfile
}   <words
```

Would handle the case where you're dealing with a lot of match patterns in *`words`* which contained a pattern per line. It takes care to escape any possible regexp *metacharacters* and then anchors the resulting pattern - at the tail of the line - so any character in *`words`* will be matched literally by `grep` and its pattern will only be matched if *word* occurs at the tail of a line - which is what I think I understand is wanted.

Usually with `grep` we don't have the metachar escapes like that because we can use `-F`ixed-string patterns - which don't have any. But, that also means, we can't use the `$` metachar to anchor the pattern, so we work with what we got.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @words      = qw ( dog cat );
my $column_num = 1;                #perl starts arrays zero.

my $regex = join( "|", map {quotemeta} @words );
$regex = qr/$regex/;

while (<>) {
    print if ( split() )[$column_num] =~ $regex;
}
```

You 'load' a regular expression with `@words` - `qw` is simply 'quoted words' e.g. space delimited. You turn that into a regular expression.

Then using the diamond operator `<>` which either reads from `<STDIN>` or opens files as listed on the command line (so `cat $file | ./myscript.pl` or `./myscript.pl <filename>` ) - we then read each line.

We check for the presence of that regular expression in the designated column number (split splits on whitespace by default).

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` with PCRE:

```
$ grep -P '^[^ ]+\s+dog|cat(?=\s|$)' file.txt 
email1.com dog
email3.com cat
```

This will print the lines where `dog` or `cat` appears only on the second column of the line.